# Wrong welcome notification

Tags: bug, status-norepro, notifications, new-users

Being a Stack Exchange evangelist, when my grandma had a cooking question, I signed her up for Seasoned Advice. She got the following joining notification:

[image: Welcome to stack overflow]

Notice the "Welcome to Stack Overflow!" message. People  joining the non-SO sites might find this strange.

EDIT (July 22):

the notification history for the account now looks as follows:

[image: Still no seasoned advice]

*There is still no Seasoned Advice notification.* Even if SO was joined two days later (after the screenshot was taken) that doesn't explain the lack of SA notification.

ANOTHER EDIT (July 22):

I tried clicking the user page link, and I got [This nonexistent page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/1542962). <s>I think there has to be a problem, even if it doesn't always occur.</s>

EDIT FINAL:

The SO account was apparently created last year. So that was the source of the confusion.

Comment: Next you get to teach her how to code. Good luck!

Comment: The icon is for Stack Overflow as well.

Comment: Maybe we can change it to Soup Overflow or Snack Overflow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was could not reproduce the issue you're describing. The account history for "Dawn Kundera"
shows that the Seasoned Advice account was created on July 19th and the StackOverflow account was created on July 21st, and that was the source of the notification on your screenshot.

[image]

Comment: do you mean July 19 and July 21? the screenshot was taken on July 19, before the account was apparently registered for SO.

Comment: The SO account was created on July 1st, **2012**.